# RadDatePicker is showing 01/01/0001 when no date selected

Tags: c#, silverlight, rad-controls, raddatepicker

I am binding a Date field to `RadDatePicker`. When there is a null value for the Date field, the `RadDatePicker` displays 01/01/0001, but I want it to remain blank.

Comment: Wow even the answer seems to be duplicated as with the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are bind not nullable datetime variable i.e (DateTime) to control then it will use default 01/01/001 date instead of Empty.... So if you want the default value as a Empty then just change the datatype of your variable which is bound to control to (DateTime?).....

DateTime ===> DateTime?

It works fine...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `SelectedDate` to null.

It is as follows:

```
Rdtp.SelectedDate = null;
```

In xaml you will have to set `DateTimeWatermarkContent` to empty as follows

`DateTimeWatermarkContent=""` in

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker x:Name="Rdtp" DateTimeWatermarkContent="" />
```

Hope Its Helpful.